# Missing icons and error message when running gnome-terminator (built from sources)

Tags: gnome-terminator

I just installed terminator **from sources** that I got [here](https://launchpad.net/terminator/trunk/0.98/+download/terminator-0.98.tar.gz).

It appears there is a dev version that works better but I just could not find it (launchpad is so messy).

When I launched a terminal I'm getting:

```
Warning: python-keybinder is not installed. This means the hide_window shortcut will be unavailable
Unable to bind hide_window key, another instance/window has it.
/home/me/programs/terminator/lib/python2.6/site-packages/terminatorlib/window.py:185: GtkWarning: Could not find the icon 'terminator'. The 'hicolor' theme
was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.
You can get a copy from:
    http://icon-theme.freedesktop.org/releases
  if icon_theme.lookup_icon(icon_name, 48, 0):
ActivityWatch plugin unavailable: please install python-notify
PluginRegistry::load_plugins: Importing plugin activitywatch.py failed: 'module' object has no attribute 'AVAILABLE
```

EDIT2:
The build and install went OK, with no message or warning. But when I launch the terminator from another terminal app, then this message appear.
And indeed most icons on the terminator are messed up (replaced by ugly X)

I tried to install `icon-theme-hicolor`, I had to build it, it went ok but I do not see ant icon in its (many) directories.

How can I get terminator working correctly ?

EDIT: I use a CentOS6.6

Comment: Context: What Operating system & distribution are you using?

Comment: Read all of the error messages, and install the dependencies (probably the dev versions), and try again. Then update the question to tell us what happened.

Comment: I use a centOS6.6, I think the 3 things are unrelated

Comment: I think they are all independent, but related. That is you have to fix them independently, but they are related in that they are all stopping the build.

Comment: OK I will, but just to be clear, the build and install of terminator works, this message is displayed when I launch it (from another terminal app) and the icons on the terminator app are messed up (though it works)